# Pivoting/reshaping a dataframe to have dates as columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, pivot, time-series

Here is my dataframe:

```
       ID        AMT          DATE
0   1496846   54.76        2015-02-11
1   1496846   195.00       2015-01-09
2   1571558   11350.00     2015-04-30
3   1498812   135.00       2014-07-11
4   1498812   157.00       2014-08-04
5   1498812   110.00       2014-09-23
6   1498812   1428.00      2015-01-28
7   1558450   4355.00      2015-01-26
8   1858606   321.52       2015-03-27
9   1849431   1046.81      2015-03-19
```

I would like to make this a dataframe consisting of time series data for each `ID`. That is, each column name is a date (sorted), and it is indexed by `ID`, and the values are the `AMT` values corresponding to each date. I can get so far as doing something like

`df.set_index("DATE").T`

but from here I'm stuck.

I also tried

`df.pivot(index='ID', columns='DATE', values='AMT')`

but this gave me an error on having duplicate entries (the `ID`s).

I envision it as transposing `DATE`, and then grouping by unique `ID` and melting `AMT` underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use `pivot_table` where there is an `aggfunc` parameter that handles duplicate indices.

```
df.pivot_table('AMT', 'DATE', 'ID', aggfunc='sum')
```

[image]

---

You'll want to choose how to handle the dups.  I put `'sum'` in there.  It defaults to `'mean'`